# Finder window left border display bug

Tags: macos, finder

I see a strange thing on all left borders of Finder windows:

[image: Left side of Finder window]

The background is 1px moved, and the rounded corner mask fails.

I thought it was only me, but I saw this on several computers (iMacs and MBP, ML).

I can't believe Apple saw this and did not fix it… Anybody know where it comes from?

EDIT
And after upgrading from 10.8 to 10.9.3, I got the same + a 2px height (instead of 1) title bar border…
It now resolves when displaying and hiding toolbar.

EDIT bis
So, I had a brand new Mac in hands, didn't install any software yet, and when I hid the Toolbar and showed the status bar, same bug.
So you *all have this* (don't you ?).

[image: Left side of Finder window]

EDIT ter
So, just updated to Yosemite, on 10.10.2, there's still a similar bug.
Am I the only one to use Finder windows without toolbar? I cant' believe no one saw this at Apple.

Comment: Huh, I do not see this (10.9.3). There are a lot of things that can be shown and hidden though: Tab, Path, Status, Side, and Tool bars. I wonder if to replicate it you have to show or hide them in a particular order. That would make it pretty easy to miss.

Comment: Whatever I show / hide, if I achieve to resolve this, when I close the window and open it again, it's back…

Comment: Is it only visible during the transition for you? I see something like the two pixel issue you mentioned, but only during the transition animation.

Comment: Oh no, it's not only during transition, it's always. I open a window, and I got this.

Comment: One year later, just tested this in 10.10 DP2 and the bug still exists.

Comment: So maybe it's… a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that's a bug that might get fixed if it's not intentional.

You can lobby for fixing at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ and posting it to https://openradar.appspot.com to get community support to duplicate your request